# Slicing specific rows and columns within a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list of lists that I convert into a matrix.

```
m = [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

n = np.matrix(m)
```

How do I go about creating a new matrix based on the first three rows and columns?

Specifically, this:

```
I = [[0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I thought the following line would work

```
I = m[0:3, 0:3]
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 3):

you are slicing a list instead of a matrix. list cannot take tuple as an argument.
Use `n[0:3,0:3]` instead of `m[0:3, 0:3]`.

Comment: It may benefit the asker to have an explanation of why this is correct.

Comment: Looks more like a typo.  Why make `n` and not use it?  The subject line also mentions the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to user1753919's answer, you can slice the list with following code:

```
In [10]: [row[0:3] for row in m[0:3]]
Out[10]: [[0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

But I recommend you to do that with the matrix. Because it's more simple.